# Multipart form request throws: Required MultipartFile parameter 'image' is not present

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, postman

I try to upload an image to a server using the postman. I am using spring to make the rest api as the followings:

[image: PostMan mutlipart request]

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPrescription", method =RequestMethod.POST)
  public  ResponseEntity<ResponseSuccessData> uploadPatientPrescription(
        @RequestBody  @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image)
        throws  IOException {
```

But it throws an error:

```
      org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: 
      Required MultipartFile parameter 'image' is not present
```

As you can see in the postman that key name is 'image' and in rest api is also @RequestParam("image").

Setting value in content type - Content-type = multipart/form-data,boundaries='--abc'

This is my spring config for multipart -

```
  @Bean
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {

  CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new      CommonsMultipartResolver();
//commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
return commonsMultipartResolver;

}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: But yeah, remove the `@RequestBody`. It's not doing anything.

Comment: Yeah you right, I was already checked by removing @RequestBody. but not work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove the header section

[image]

Please remove the - Content-Type : multipart/form-data;boundary='abc' setting in the header part of postman

Answer (score 2):

```
@RestController
public class UserOfferController {

// upload image 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadimage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObjectBean> uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile file) {
        int statusCode;
        String msg;
        Object data = null;
        long maxsize = configuredValue.getFileMaxAcceptedSize();

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {

                String name = file.getOriginalFilename();

                String imagePath = "path to save your image ";


                try {
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(imagePath)));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    statusCode = 200;
                    msg = "DONE";
                    data = true;

                }  catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    statusCode = 500;
                    msg = "FAIL";
                    data = false;

                }

        } else {
            statusCode = 500;
            msg = "FAIL";
            data = false;
        }
        responseData.setStatusCode(statusCode);
        responseData.setStatusMsg(msg);
        responseData.setData(data);
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseObjectBean>(responseData, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    }
```

Add these line in spring.xml

```
    <!-- mutipart upload configuration -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024" />
        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="2048" />
    </bean>
```

[image]

Comment: Your rest api and my rest is same , if i was removed the @RequestBody annotation

Comment: add the given line in spring.xml . I am sure then it will works

Comment: I was just updated the question, adding the configuration code of multipart in spring .Please see it

Comment: Content-Type    - multipart/form-data;boundary="--prescriptionImage"

Comment: please remove the header and try it please informed me its work or not

Comment: working man. Thanks. I am going to updated my question (adding the header information).Can you update the answer . So , I can accept you answer

Comment: Ok dude.please give me right and a vote in my answer

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Abhijit Chowdhury answer, if you are using spring security still you can remove `Content-Type` and just keep your token in the header, no need to remove everything from the header.

Also, it is important to restart postman.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove header section in POSTMAN.

2.In your API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPrescription", method =RequestMethod.POST)
      public  ResponseEntity<ResponseSuccessData> uploadPatientPrescription(
            @RequestBody  @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image)
            throws  IOException {}
```

add the following:

```
consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
```

so it becomes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPrescription", method =RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  public  ResponseEntity<ResponseSuccessData> uploadPatientPrescription(
        @RequestBody  @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image)
        throws  IOException {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `@RequestBody @RequestParam("image")` to just `@RequestBody("image")`.
The first statement is not valid, see - [Spring uploading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/).

Comment: The annotation @ResponseBody is disallowed for this location

Comment: Did you mean _to just `@RequestParam("image")`_?

Comment: I was the rest from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884711/spring-file-upload-restful-web-service