# Liferay rest endpoint for files upload

Tags: java, spring, rest, liferay

I am trying to create a REST endpoint in Liferay for files upload, but ActionRequest cannot be used. When I try to use it I keep getting:

```
Handler execution resulted in exception: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present resourceId:personUpload
```

My Controller:

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "personUpload")
public List<ChInsuredPerson> uploadExcel(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    List<ChInsuredPerson> insuredPeople = new ArrayList<ChInsuredPerson>();
    try {
        insuredPeople = personUploadService.extractInsuredPersons(file.getInputStream());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return insuredPeople;

}
```

I am calling the endpoint with Postman like this:
[image]

Comment: what Liferay version are you running?

Comment: Have you seen the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022087/multipart-form-request-throws-required-multipartfile-parameter-image-is-not-p