# Uploading file to database using spring boot hibernate

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to upload file in database, this is what i have tried

domain:

```
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
    private byte[] uploadData;
```

controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadData" , consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity< DataInfo > uploaddata(@Valid @RequestBody DataInfo dataInfo){
        DataInfo uploadData = dataR.save(dataInfo);
        return new ResponseEntity("OK",HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

This is the postman response

> {
>       "timestamp": 1512210715164,
>       "status": 415,
>       "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
>       "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
>       "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported",
>       "path": "/api/uploadData" }

What I am doing wrong ? please help . Here I have to upload the file in to database. The data info contains information with a attachment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring : File Upload RESTFUL Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884711/spring-file-upload-restful-web-service)

Comment: No I am having a domain , the web client should send data information which include the attachment as a payload

Comment: Your mapping is set to `consumes = "application/json"`. You are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The controller is returning an exception. What exactly are you posting? Without further information, the accepted answer to davioooh's duplicate flag would be appropriate.

Comment: Please put your client code or payload which you have receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files have to be handled as a multipart data when you try sending from a client. (You can refer here to know more about the Multipart request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean))

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Document> UploadFile( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // Upload Logic
}
```

Additionally, you can specify the file size in your service properties like below:

```
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10mb
      max-request-size: 12mb
```